# Python Requests: response object does not contain 'status' header

Tags: python, http-status-codes, python-requests

This is Requests 1.1.0 and Python 2.6.4 (also same behavior on Python 2.7.2).

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> print response.headers.get('status')
None
```

According to the docs, there should be a headers['status'] entry with a string like "200 OK".

Here is the full contents of the headers dict:

```
>>> response.headers 
{'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'set-cookie': 'PREF=ID=74b29ee465454efd:FF=0:TM=1362094463:LM=1362094463:S=Xa96iJQX_9BrC-Vm; expires=Sat, 28-Feb-2015 23:34:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com, NID=67=IH21bLPTK2gLTHCyDCMEs3oN5g1uMV99U4Wsc2YA00AbFt4fQCoywQNEQU0pR6VuaNhhQGFCsqdr0FnWbPcym-pizo0xVuS6WBJ9EOTeSFARpzrsiHh6HNnaQeCnxCSH; expires=Fri, 30-Aug-2013 23:34:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly', 'expires': '-1', 'server': 'gws', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Thu, 28 Feb 2013 23:34:23 GMT', 'p3p': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN'}
```

[Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-headers) is where I got the idea that this dict should contain a 'status' entry.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the "reason"

```
>>> x=requests.get("http://apple.adam.gs")
>>> x.reason
'OK'
>>>
```

custom.php contains:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 Testing")
```

Results in:

```
>>> x=requests.get("http://apple.adam.gs/custom.php")
>>> print x.reason
Testing
>>>
```